# automatic folder creation in bash

Tags: bash

I have a folder with a nested structure of sub-folders in it. I want to create another folder and copy that structure to in. However, I only want to keep the first level of the structure. To be more clear, imagine 1 folder containing 100 folders each of which having some other nested levels of folders. I want to  create a separate folder, somewhere else, in which I create 100 folders with the exact same names. That's it. No need to copying the contents of each folder.

Is it possible to this in one line of code via piping, and mkdir or something else?

Comment: The task is clear. Now after you've described what you want, what do you expect us to do?

Comment: @AxelAmthor just added info the question. Totally forgot about asking the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the folderstructure to some file

```
find . -type d > /tmp/dirs.txt
```

cd into your new folder and create the directories using

```
xargs mkdir -p < /tmp/dirs.txt
```

Or if you have spaces in the foldernames (which is never a good idea):

```
find . -type d -print0 > /tmp/dirs.txt  
xargs -0 mkdir -p < /tmp/dirs.txt
```

If you only want the first level of structure, add `-maxdepth 1` to the find command.

Comment: Not working. 1) splits folder names with space and creates separate folders based on each split name! 2) copies the whole structure where I wanted to have a copy of the first level of the hierarchy.

Comment: you should never uses spaces in foldernames. However, I'll update he answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use find like this to create directories found at 1st level:

```
find ./A -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir mkdir "$PWD/B/{}" \;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. "Error: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘A/BlackAndWhite’: File exists".  What I tried: "find A -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir B/'{}' +"